# Problem with pandas 'to_csv' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects)

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I want to output a Pandas groupby dataframe to CSV. Tried various StackOverflow solutions but they have not worked.

Python 3.7

[This is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9iaD.png)

This is my code

```
groups = clustering_df.groupby(clustering_df['Family Number'])
groups.apply(lambda clustering_df: clustering_df.sort_values(by=['Family Number']))
groups.to_csv('grouped.csv')
```

**Error Message**

(AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_csv' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

```
groups = clustering_df.groupby(clustering_df['Family Number'])
groups = groups.apply(lambda clustering_df: clustering_df.sort_values(by=['Family Number']))
groups.to_csv('grouped.csv')
```

What you have done is, not saved the groupby-apply variable. It would get applied and might throw output depending on what IDE/Notebook you use. But to save it into a file, you will have to apply the function on the groupby object, save it into a variable and you can save the file.

Chaining works as well:

```
groups = clustering_df.groupby(clustering_df['Family Number']).apply(lambda clustering_df: clustering_df.sort_values(by=['Family Number']))
groups.to_csv("grouped.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out :)

Comment: I was able to get a nice output from this! :) @pissall Would it be possible that in the .csv sheet I get the the rows of what I'm grouping by (in this case _Family Number_) merged already?

Comment: What does the csv look like? *Family Number* should be there in it

Comment: [image] (https://ibb.co/X8pr3k6) What I want is in red but what I get is in blue (this is from the csv, however from the terminal it give the output in red [image2] (https://ibb.co/wNQfrrf) @pissall